# There is like a wall in my screen and im not sure how to get rid of it, the more I zoom out the worse it gets.(new to blender)

Tags: clipping

[image: This is what I see when looking thorough Blender]

[image: This is what I see when looking thorough Blender]
When ever I zoom in I can see my objects better, but when I zoom out the screen gets covered not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Hello and welcome, this question was closed as a duplicate and linked to another question.  See the answers there, should solve your problem :)